# Html Mailto not working with Calculated Column Spaces

Tags: calculated-column, html

In a list, I have a calculated column where I created a hyperlink button to send an email via html mailto. 
The email I would like to build takes information from other single line of text columns such as the email of the recipient, the name of the project the email is about.

This the code I am using :

```
="<a href=mailto:"&[Creator email]&"?subject="&[Project-Name]&" &body=This%20is%20a%20test. '></A>"
```

While the [Creator Email] is working properly as there is no space in the text in the column (as it is an email adress), things get different when it is the name of the project.For example if the name of the project is pilot project, the email created only shows the word pilot and stops working and does not show the rest of the instructions of the code.

Meaning where there is a space in the text of the column I am referring to, my code stops working.

How could I solve the problem ?

Comment: what's your SharePoint version?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try using single quotes like below?

```
="<a href=mailto:'&[Creator email]&'?subject='&[Project-Name]&' &body=This%20is%20a%20test></A>"
```

Even if above doesnt work, this is something to do with your formatting of quotes only.

Comment: Thank you for this answer but it is not going through with single quotes.. I just tried